# Slim Framework 3 LIMIT ROUTE do not go beyond designed endpoint

Tags: php, rest, slim

I've developed RESTful API using Slim Framework 3

My concern, How Could I limit the route as following:

My endpoint: `my.api.com:/checkstatus/{card_number}`

However I would like to throw a JSON error response when the user hits `my.api.com/{card_number}/any-call*` and do not let him go beyond `/checkstatus/{card_number}`

I would like to return `404` header

Please advice

Comment: So is /checkstatus/ a route after /any-call*?? I guess which routes are you wanting to throw the 404 at?

Comment: Slim will return 404 for any route you have not defined.